# Intent.PutExtra на несколько Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity, android-intent

есть несколько активити, в том числе и `settings_activity`. В `settings_activity` есть несколько кнопок (20% (btSound20), 40% (btnSound40), 60% (btnSoun60), 80% (btnSound80), 100% (btnSound100)), эти кнопки регулируют звук в файле MainActivity а именно `MediaPlayer`. В `settings_activity`есть ключ передающий нажатие в другое активити

```
intent80.putExtra("Sound20", 0.8f);
```

А активити в которое нужно передавать этот ключ два,т.к вот как передать этот ключ сразу в 2 активити.

Comment: на самом деле можно такое сделать, но мне что-то подсказывает, что вам просто необходимо использовать SharedPreferences он очень подходит для вот таких кейсов.

Comment: а как сделать то так?

Answer (score 2):

Для таких целей удобно использовать `SharedPreferences`. В настройках Вы записываете необходимые параметры, а затем из любого места без проблем их можно прочитать, к тому же после перезапуска приложения данные останутся в памяти.

**Записать пару ключ-значение:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

**Прочитать значение ключа:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String s = sharedPref.getString("key");
```

Comment: Только `getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` с одинаковым `name` в обоих случаях, иначе другая `Activity` получит другое хранилище, а не то, в которое были записаны данные.

Comment: @woesss, да, поправил